# Summarized Production Report (Static Filters)

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report to be developed with specific static format:

[image]

for each row I have to filter based on the requirements mentioned in the screen shot i.e.

for Property I should generate Premium for Current Year and Previous Years for both Non KSA and KSA based on the filters: cover Type= Facultative and Cover Type = Insurance and Line Of Business = Property.

and so on and so on.

Any idea how to do that using report builder?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you need a static format based upon 2 filters, cover type and line of business.

I am presuming these field are already populated within your dataset.

click on tablix and go to properties, click on filters, click add. under expression pull down field name for cover type,text, operator "=" , value type in  "Faculative, Insurance" .

Do the same for line of business, except type in "Property".

Now your report will be hard coded for a match against this criterion.